# How to dynamically open a method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, methods

I want to dynamically open a method and return a value based on the input field. I am trying to ask what I want with an example here. If I could succeed this example, I would do what I want.

Assume I have a class called Greetings which has a method called greet() which takes message as argument.

```
class Greetings
   def self.greet(message)
      return "good morning" if message=="gm"
      return "evening" if message=="ge"
      return "good afternoon" if message=="ga"
   end
end
```

When I do a `Greetings.greet("ge")`, I get "evening" as the output. I want to change this behavior without changing the above Greetings class (obvious reason is that its an external library).

My question here is simple. What should I do when say I call `Greetings.greet("ge")` should return me "A Very Good Evening" and for all the other inputs, it should return what the original class returns. I know something about dynamically opening a class in Ruby but how would I delegate the method to parent for the other cases?

And I would be writing this inside the config/initializers folder since I am using Rails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Method aliasing

You can alias your old method as `old_greet` for example, and redefine with your own:

```
class Greetings
  class << self
    alias_method :old_greet, :greet

    def greet(message)
      (message == "ge") ? "A Very Good Evening" : old_greet(message)
    end
  end
end
```

and then you can:

```
puts Greetings.greet("ge")
```

#### Method chaining

With the Rails [`alias_method_chain`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_method_chain) feature:

```
class Greetings
  class << self
    def greet_with_modifications(message)
      (message == "ge") ? "A Very Good Evening" : greet_without_modifications(message)
    end

    alias_method_chain :greet, :modifications
  end
end
```

and then you can:

```
puts Greetings.greet("ge")
```

#### Extending class

You can create your own class which extends the original like this:

```
module My
  class Greetings < ::Greetings
    def self.greet(message)
      case message
        when "ge"
          "A Very Good Evening"
        else
          super(message)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then you can:

```
puts My::Greetings.greet("ge")
```

Comment: Thanks for such a nice written answer!!

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this to reopen the class in your code:

```
Greetings.class_eval do
  class << self
    alias :old_greet :greet
  end
  def self.greet(message)
    return "a very good evening" if message == "ge"
    old_greet(message)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you just reopen the class? is the class_eval needed?

Comment: Funny, we basically posted identical solution, just you used class eval and I directly reopened the class. :-)

Comment: With reopening the class, if the class doesn't already exist it will create it. With class_eval, if the class doesn't already exist, an error will be thrown.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about class_eval

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like

```
class Greetings
  class << self
    alias :old_greet :greet
  end

  def self.greet(message)
    return "A very good evening" if message == 'ge'
    old_greet(message)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks István, I just wrote the code directly here and obviously confused the class name with the method name. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about this, simply?

```
class Greetings
   def self.greet(message)
      return "good morning" if message=="gm"
      return "evening" if message=="ge"
      return "good afternoon" if message=="ga"
   end
end

class GreetingsOverloaded < Greetings
  def self.greet(message)
      return "A Very Good Evenin" if message=="ge"
      super
   end
end

puts Greetings.greet("ge")
puts GreetingsOverloaded.greet("ge")
```